# Are there any uml tools on Ubuntu ?

Tags: ubuntu, uml, ubuntu-10.04

Are there any UML tools (as Rose) on Ubuntu?

Comment: This is not a programming question nor a complete Ubuntu question. I'm not sure but http://ubuntu.stackexchange.com/ might be the right place to post this question.

Comment: I'm not sure I can agree there, @bdhar. The FAQ specifically states "software tools commonly used by programmers". It might be suitable for ubuntu-se _as well_ but I still think it's appropriate here.

Comment: @paxdiablo-thanks for the clarification! :)

Comment: https://staruml.io/download

Comment: https://staruml.io/download/releases/StarUML-3.1.1.AppImage works well for Ubuntu 20.04

Answer (score 42, accepted):

I use **Dia** for drawing UML diagrams (as well as other diagrams), but it cannot generate code (at least not without some additional tools, like **dia2code**).  It's more like a general-purpose diagram drawing tool with a decent support for UML.

**Umbrello** is a tool dedicated to UML-based modelling.  It's comparable to Dia in terms of drawing, plus it can export *and* import code from/to several languages.

---

The above apps are, in my opinion, the best you can get from Ubuntu.  Nevertheless, there are several other apps/libraries that are somehow related to UML modelling.  Open *System -> Administration -> Synaptic Package Manager* and type "uml" in the search box.

Comment: for lucid, 10.04 w/ gnome Umbrello is crashing every 20 mins

Comment: Umbrello looks like it hasn't been touched since 2008.

Answer (score 9):

I use argoUML, and it can also generate code. It seems it is not very updated to the last UML standards, but it can succesfully generate C++, Python, and PHP code. I find it very useful.

http://argouml.tigris.org/

More info at:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ArgoUML

Comment: There is a PPA for ArgoUML called "GetDebs".  Read more here:  http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/ppa/getdeb_apps?dist=precise

Answer (score 8):

Try a **WEB-based modeling tool** so that you get rid of the OS contraints! I recommend [**GENMYMODEL**](http://www.genmymodel.com) an UML-compliant online tool. **All you need is a web browser** in Ubuntu as it works on Chrome, Firefox and IE.

Comment: Awesome web-based tool

Answer (score 4):

I use UMLet. http://www.umlet.com/

Download, extract, then type the following to run:

```
chmod +x umlet.sh
./umlet.sh
```

Happy modelling.

Comment: the recent version on Ubuntu is very buggy. It constantly freezes, for instance, when the user is trying to navigate through folders in the open menu, etc.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't mind using java-apps then you should get an eye on [yed](http://www.yworks.com/en/products_yed_about.html). Graphs look a bit nicer than in dia. Dia is fine though.

Answer (score 2):

*Dia* is a powerful program that handles UML quite well.

Comment: And the resulting diagrams look horrible. Is true that Dia can handle a lot of things well, but I believe they should "hire" an artist to improve the looks of their resulting pictures.

Comment: @Andrei True, but on the bright side: when you see a diagram you immediately know whether it was made using Dia :)

Comment: That's subjective. In my opinion, they look very nice and professional.

Comment: It looks a heck of a lot better than it did 5 years ago.

Answer (score 2):

The best UML tool I have used is Asta Uml tool which has a community edition.

http://astah.net/editions/community

Comment: The community version has been discontinued.

Answer (score 1):

I used Dia once in a while, but I do not like it.

I've recently tried [Gaphor](http://gaphor.sourceforge.net/), which doesn't try to address other diagrams than UML and which is pretty good. I'd really give Gaphor a try if I were you.

Comment: Sadly, Gaphor crashes on Ubuntu 12.10. (Though according to the bugreport, it does work on 13.04.)

Answer (score 0):

Go for  Eclipse Modeling Tools. I am just going for it, you may install it on top of existing eclipse http://www.vogella.de/articles/UML/article.html

It is platform independent. It is developed constantly.

Answer (score 0):

I used EclipseUML Omondo with Ubuntu. It worked really well but the price of the tool is really too high !!

Answer (score 0):

You can use Enterprise Architect with Wine:
http://www.sparxsystems.com/support/faq/enterprise-architect-WINE.html

Answer (score 0):

I'm using [BOUML](http://www.bouml.fr/) (version<5.0 because it's not under GPL licence anymore) as it comes with some reverse engineering and code generation capabilities, but also because it can export [XMI](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_Metadata_Interchange) files.

Comment: http://sourceforge.net/projects/douml/ check out my fork of Bouml. I've added and changed a lot of stuff and it's still GPL.

Comment: Wonderfull! I'll check it out right now!

Comment: I see from your profile that you are a web developer - pls notify me if there are errors in php part of Douml. I mostly concentrated on C++ so there might be some.

Comment: Actually... Only the Windows version is available. Is it possible for me to compile it on GNU/Linux?

Comment: Yes, there are general guidelines for this in readme.md, plus this guy maintains deb builds : https://launchpad.net/~pasgui/+archive/ppa/

Answer (score 0):

There's also Visual Paradigm available. If you don't want to/can't pay for it you can use its [Community Edition](http://www.visual-paradigm.com/download/vpuml.jsp?edition=ce). Caveats:you're limited to non-commercials projects and can only draw one diagram per type (I'm not sure about this last one, at least, when VP was in version 7 had that restriction).

Bye!.